# Nuxt 3 dynamic route and NuxtLink not working together

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, vue-router, nuxtjs3

I created a dynamic route `/dashboard/[username].vue`. When I navigate to this page by typing in the url, everything works fine and `route.params.username` is set to the value passed in the url. However, when I navigate to this page via `NuxtLink`, `route.params` is an empty object, although the url is set correctly. My `NuxtLink` looks like this:

```html
<NuxtLink
  class="btn btn-primary"
  :to="{ name: 'dashboard-username', params: { username } }"
  >Continue</NuxtLink
>
```

I've tried this as well, which leads to the same result:

```html
<NuxtLink
  class="btn btn-primary"
  :to="`/dashboard/${username}`"
  >Continue</NuxtLink
>
```

Am I doing something wrong? Personally, I think this behaviour is strange. After navigating to the dashboard using the link, the parameter is undefined. But when I reload the same page, suddenly the value is set correctly.

Comment: Are you sure the username variable is set before navigating to the 'dashboard/[username]'. Where does the username get its value from?

Comment: It's set by an text input field and bound using v-model. I am 100% sure this variable works correctly, since the url is set correctly after navigating . However, route.params is empty, but if I refresh the same page, it is set. It seems to me like a problem with the router/SPA.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have missed the useRoute composable on the dynamic [username].vue page like this:

```
<script setup>
const route = useRoute();
const username = route.params.username;
</script>
```

And then u can use the variable in your template like this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        Hello {{ username }}!
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that's exactly what I am doing in [username].vue. Like I said, I guess it's a problem with the router, since it works when I navigate to the page via typing in the url in the address bar.

Comment: That is so weird, because I am doing the exact same thing. Have you also tried rerunning npm run dev? Sometimes when you add new pages while npm run dev is still running it can give the error you are getting.

Comment: Restarting didn't fix it, but reinstalling the packages did the trick. Thank you for your help buddy! :)

Comment: No problem! Glad it worked out in the end.

Comment: yeah but i wish to add things like this, `<nuxt-link :to="{name:'events[id]', params:{id:eventDetail.id}}">{{eventDetail.title}} </nuxt-link>` but no luck

Answer (score -1):

If you get the data from an api endpoint can you do this in your [something].vue file:

```
<script setup>
  const route = useRoute()
  const {data: user} = 
  useFetch(https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${route.params.id})
</script>
<template>
  <div>
    <ClientOnly>
        <h1>Hello {{ user.name }}</h1>
        <h1>{{ user.email }}</h1>
        <h1>{{ user.username }}</h1>
        <h1>{{ user.phone }}</h1>
    </ClientOnly>
 </div>
</template>
```